# Can't get rid of gap between images?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a question about positioning my website. As you can see in the IMG below, there is a gap between two of my images for some odd reason: http://puu.sh/6SWgu.png

I am trying to get rid of that gap, but I can't figure out why.

**EDIT**
(I don't know who deleted the other comment someone left, but I tried that one with a little bit of configuration and it worked.)

(Question is, will this new code hurt any process as I continue coding in my website?)

Here is the **NEW** content:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="images/header.png" />
    </div>
    <img src="images/navbar.png" />
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="http://www.voyage-us.com">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.voyage-us.com/xenforo/upload/index.php">Forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Streams</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div vertical-align: top; ><img src="images/mainbody.png" /></div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>&copy;2014 Rythmn Designs<p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background: url("http://puu.sh/6RlKi.png")
}

#page-wrap
{
width: 1019px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header
{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}

#nav
{
height: 0.1px;
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0.1px;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin: -14px;
}

#nav li a
{
position:relative;
top: -12px;
display: block;
width: 100px;
float: left;
color: white;
font-size:  14.09px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family:"BankGothic Md BT"
}

#nav li a:hover, #nav li a:active
{
color: red;
}

#footer
{
background: #181818;
color: white;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-top: 15px solid #828080;
text-align: center;
font-family:"BankGothic Md BT";
font-size:  12px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can set the navigation margin-bottom in negative or the main body image margin top as negative if your 0 margin or padding isn't working

Comment: Hmm - I don't think I understand fully what you mean.

Comment: u can try margin-top:-20px; for your body image

Comment: I just tried doing that. It only moves the body image up VERY little and won't go up anymore even if I raise the negative (IE. -50px).

Comment: then u can try the whole navigation margin-bottom: -20px or -50px;